# Sharing pages library as catalog in sharepoint 2013

Tags: managed-metadata, cross-site-publishing

I have a problem in SharePoint 2013 cross site publishing. I have one authoring site and 10 publishing clinic sites. I create article pages on my authoring site and want share in different clinic sites so I tag my page with terms of global term set (names of my clinics) and share my page library as catalog but I **can't share page library as catalog when I set "Allow multiple values" for managed metadata column**, because I can't choose navigation hierarchy then (it doesn't bring managed metadata column which I used for tagging and just bring "None"). When I don't check "allow multiple values" and just tag my page with one term everything is ok and I share my catalog but I want to tag my page for different clinics and connect to catalog from that clinics and use appropriate term for navigation. Can you help me please?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title